# Removing characters from dataframe returns concatenated strings

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I'm trying to replace unwanted characters in my dataframe with a whitespace with this line:

```
df['wod'].replace(to_replace=r'[^A-Za-z0-9%-/]',value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The result I'm getting is that the unwanted characters are removed however the output is now concatenated. What am I doing wrong? Really appreciate your feedback!

| date | wod |
| --- | --- |
| 01.05.2021 | ortime1milerun50wallballshots201450hollowrocks1krow50hol. |

Comment: The space is matched, that is why. Also, `%-/` create a range, I doubt you expected that. Use `r'[^A-Za-z0-9%/\s-]'`

Comment: Could you provide your original string and expected output? That would help us to understand what you're trying to achieve.